# Android studio 2.0 doesn't run app on emulator

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-emulator, startup

I am a beginner to Android but have experience in working with Java and J2EE. I am just trying to create a simple android app with the default login activity. And when I try to run this app in the emulator from "Android Studio 2.0" and SDK from "Preview channel" I don't even see my app in the emulator.

Few things I tried,

- Recreated the AVD
- Deleted and recreated the project
- Disabled or unchecked "Enable ADB integration" from Tools > Android

I couldn't try it with a real device as I couldn't get hold of one. Any thoughts or insights would be great. I know being a newbie and trying preview or canary is a bad idea but was just curious

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question but a suggestion, try using genymotion.

Comment: @MsYvetteI haven't got a chance to try it with stable channel

Comment: Do you see the emulator or it doesn't even start?

Comment: @MT-Wizard The emulator does start, but I just didn't see my app.. It started working fine in the next update from `Preview channel` but there were no reported issues or fixes on the release notes.. Guess it was an intermittent issue or something

Answer (score 0):

Try the following 2 things first:

1. It takes several minutes for the emulator to come up so you may have to wait while all that is coming up is the android logo. When available, click on the home icon and it will get to a screen asking you to swipe in order to startup, here press F2 to get into the phone screen and then your app.
2. Check the messages on the Android Studio Monitor to see if anything useful comes up to indicate what the problem is.

If the above 2 don't help, try installing the following items, using the Android Studio SDK Manager and running the emulator after the installs:

1. Install the Atom x86 system image (assuming you are using an x86/32 bit processor) rather than the ARM EABI v7 that they give on the android studio website.
2. Install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer).

Finally, if it still doesn't work then delete all the existing AVDs within Android Studio and create a new one with the following settings:

1. Device = Nexus S API 23
2. Resolution = 480 x 800 hdpi
3. Emulated Performance: Use host GPU = unticked
4. Emulated Performance: Store a snapshot for faster startup = ticked

Once your AVD is setup close and save your project. Then go back in and run your app.